# How do I add a nullable data type to mysql with entity framework?

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to change an Entity Framework Core 2.2 app from MSSQL to MySQL. When I try run `dotnet ef database update`, I get

> The property
>   '{className}.{property}' could
>   not be mapped, because it is of type 'Nullable' which is not
>   a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly
>   map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or
>   by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Definition of {property}:

```
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 999999999999)]
    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal? {property} { get; set; }
```

I am using Visual Studio Code on Mac OS so I do not have access to any of the MS GUI tools.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is it required if it's nullable?

Comment: When using [Required], it mean, the field will always expect data whenever a record is created or updated. So, it is either you remove [Required] or you don't make it null

Comment: I believe it is because the data type passed back from the API has to be nullable for validation reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `[Column(TypeName = "Money")]` doesn't exist in MySQL. To my future self: just stick to SQL server if it's already in place...